# How can I make a WIN 10 desktop shortcut open a link in Edge, even though Chrome is the default browser?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, microsoft-edge

Chrome is set as the default browser on my Windows 10 computer. However, I want to create a shortcut on the desktop to YouTube.com that opens in Microsoft Edge. How can I do this?

Comment: Just create a shortcut to Edge and set the home page to YouTube.

Comment: See [How to open URL in Microsoft Edge from the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164253/how-to-open-url-in-microsoft-edge-from-the-command-line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new shortcut with the following Path:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start microsoft-edge:http://www.youtube.com
```

You can then change the icon by right clicking and going to the Shortcut tab. From there, click "Change Icon" and click browse. Then go to `C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe` and click MicrosoftEdge to get its Icon. Finally click OK on all open dialog boxes.

Comment: This worked great, thank you! If you happen to know of a way to hide the CMD window that briefly pops up, I'd love to know, but it's not a big deal.

Comment: Create a shortcut with the following target, leaving out the CMD.. and Start part:

`microsoft-edge:http://www.youtube.com`


And, if you want to add Edge to the right-click menu, this script might help.

[Open .URL Files Using Different Browsers from the Right-Click Menu](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/open-url-shortcuts-different-browsers-right-click-menu/)