# Windows 10 Using cmd.exe to open an IE browser

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, internet-explorer

I found [this very old post](https://superuser.com/questions/1097333/how-can-i-make-a-win-10-desktop-shortcut-open-a-link-in-edge-even-though-chrome/1474482#1474482) about opening a specific desktop shortcut for YouTube in Edge, not Chrome.  I would like to do the same, but open in IE, not Edge.

I doubt that anyone will see my question I just asked on that post just now, so does anyone know what I need to change in the below to make the command open in IE? I assume it is just the bold part that needs changing?

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start microsoft-edge:http://www.youtube.com
```

Comment: please spend a minute to take the [tour] to understand how this site works. It's not a forum so don't post answers to ask things. Also learn [how to format](https://superuser.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Edge is a UWP app so obviously calling it from command line must be different

Answer (score 1):

It should be `iexplore` to invoke internet explorer.

Try this from cmd prompt to verify if it works

```
start iexplore http://www.youtube.com
```

so in the shortcut:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start iexplore http://www.youtube.com
```

notice there's no colon between `iexplore` and the url